# What is the correct stucture of a Realm C++ project files and how to run the project?

Tags: c++, mongodb, cmake, makefile, realm

I am very new to Realm. I am using Realm C++ SDK to make a sample database that can sync with MongoDB Atlas.

As a summary of what I did,

1. I built the Realm C++ SDK (this [github issue](https://github.com/realm/realm-cpp/issues/74#issue-1735677224) shows how I built the SDK)
2. I made a Realm app on MongoDB Atlas
3. I pulled the Realm app `MyRealmApp` from terminal using `realm-cli`, from directory `realm_test`
4. I made modification on the `realm_test/MyRealmApp/auth/providers.json` and `realm_test/MyRealmApp/sync/config.json` to fulfill the [prerequisites](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/cpp/quick-start/#prerequisites)

After building the SDK following the [documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/cpp/install/#install), and creating an app that fulfills the [prerequisites](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/cpp/quick-start/#prerequisites), this is the resulting project file structure.

```
.realm_test
├──build
|   ├── ... //everything inside 'build' is generated by CMakeLists.txt
|   
├──CMakeLists.txt //this file builds the SDK
|   
├──main.cpp //this is the test code I used when building the SDK
|   
├──MyRealmApp //this is the app I created after building the SDK, everything under this is generated, with some modification
|   |   
|   ├──auth
|   |   ├──custom_user_data.json
|   |   ├──providers.json
|   |   
|   ├──data_sources
|   |   ├──mongodb-atlas
|   |       ├──config.json
|   |   
|   ├──environments
|   |   ├──development.json
|   |   ├──no-environment.json
|   |   ├──production.json
|   |   ├──qa.json
|   |   ├──testing.json
|   |   
|   ├──functions
|   |   ├──config.json
|   |   
|   ├──graphql
|   |   ├──custom_resovlers
|   |       ├──config.json
|   |   
|   ├──http_endpoints
|   |   ├──config.json
|   |   
|   ├──log_forwarders
|   |   
|   ├──services
|   |   
|   ├──sync
|   |   ├──config.json
|   |
|   ├──values
|
├──realm_config.json
```

The next step is, I want to access and use the DB through C++ codes, as in the [quick start](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/cpp/quick-start/#initialize-the-app).

My question is,

1. Is my current project file structure correct?
2. Where should I put the C++ source codes?
3. How to build and run the Realm project?

   - Do I need to remove the `./realm_test/build`, modify the CMakeLists.txt and run `cmake` again?
   - If I need to modify the CMakeLists.txt, which part do I need to modify? (I am also new to CMake)

Comment: For clarity, did you follow this guide [Realm C++ SDK](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/cpp/install/)?

Comment: Yes, I followed its installation instruction, the only difference is I added `set(REALM_USE_SYSTEM_OPENSSL ON)` to the CMakeList.txt so that it uses whatever version of OpenSSL I have in my machine, as suggested in this [post](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/openssl-version-for-realm-c-sdk/229103). Also, I use `cmake -DREALM_CPP_NO_TESTS=1 ..` when performing the `cmake` step, as suggested in this [github issue](https://github.com/realm/realm-cpp/issues/74#issue-1735677224).